# Cython: how to pass a c++ class as an argument to a Cython class that wraps the c++ class?

Tags: c++, pointers, cython

I am fighting with CYTHON, trying to make a copy of a C++ class in a Python class.
I the .pxd I have:

```
cdef extern from "MyCppClass.h":
    cdef cppclass MyCppClass:
        MyCppClass ()
        int        Copy(MyCppClass * Source)


cdef class MyPyClass:
    cdef MyCppClass * thisptr
    cdef copy(self, MyCppClass *s)
```

and in the .pyx I have

```
cdef class MyPyClass: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.thisptr = new MyCppClass ()

    cdef copy(self, MyCppClass * s):    
         self.thisptr.Copy(s)
```

The compilation is ok.

Then I try to use it in another Cython module:

```
A=new MyCppClass()
pA=MyPyClass()
… do some stuff on A
p1.copy(A)
```

And I get the usual “cannot convert to Python object”
I have tried a lot of things to copy, like :

```
 cdef getThisptr(self):
    return self.thisptr

A=new MyCppClass()
pA=MyPyClass()
B=pA.getThisptr()
B.Copy(A)
```

But nothing works!

It sounds very basic in Cython, but I am still waiting for a solution…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `cimport`. In order for Cython to know about your `cdef` defined types and functions you need to add

```
from module_name cimport MyPyClass
```

Otherwise it just assumes that `Copy` is a Python function accepting a Python object.

[The relevant bit of documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html)

Comment: Thank's a lot ! I had `from module_name import MyPyClass` and I forgot the `cimport` witch is not evident for me since MyPyClass is a Python class, not a C++ class.